# Unable to do Windows update through batchpatch

Tags: windows, wmi, rpc, windows-firewall

Unable to do the windows update through batch patch. When I tried to check for available updates, some instances are showing the error message as “Error 1601: Failed to retrieve WMI info. The RPC server is unavailable".

I have tried the below troubleshooting steps for those instances which are showing error.
1.       Windows Firewall – opened ports 135 and 445 
2.       Checked the RPC service to see if it is running and set to automatic
3.       If the instance is stopped, we have left it alone

Followed this KB https://batchpatch.com/troubleshooting-common-errors-in-batchpatch no luck. Anyone who has experience or idea what is wrong please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It's peculiar that you would post on stackoverflow rather than contacting BatchPatch support directly (https://batchpatch.com/contact) or posting on the support forum (https://batchpatch.com/forum).

The page that you linked (batchpatch.com/troubleshooting-common-errors-in-batchpatch) contains additional links for troubleshooting the 'RPC server is unavailable' error.  It specifically points to these two links:

batchpatch.com/using-batchpatch-with-windows-firewall

batchpatch.com/batchpatch-ports

It is not sufficient to just open 135 and 445 in the Windows Firewall.  You must open 'File and Printer sharing' and 'Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).'  In your case, probably the error is occurring because you did not open 'Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).'

The above link also further explains:

> In order for WMI to work properly… The target computer must be able to
> receive and process RPC (Remote Procedure Call) requests. Both the WMI
> and RPC services must be running on the target computer. If you’re
> using Windows Firewall on the target computer, then please follow the
> instructions on this page to configure it properly: Using BatchPatch
> with Windows Firewall
> (batchpatch.com/using-batchpatch-with-windows-firewall).
>
> If you are using a hardware firewall, the configuration for WMI can
> potentially be a bit trickier, depending on the particular firewall
> device. WMI connections, by default, are not established on a
> static/fixed port. Instead WMI uses dynamic port configuration for its
> connections, which means that the actual ports used for a given
> connection are established on-the-fly at the time of connection. Each
> connection will end up using different ports. In the context of a
> classic hardware firewall, this used to be a problem because hardware
> firewalls would typically require any open ports to be configured
> manually. An enterprise firewall administrator could never know in
> advance which ports would need to be opened. However, fortunately many
> modern firewalls now implement DCE/RPC, which solves this problem and
> allows the use of dynamic ports for WMI/RPC. If you have a network
> level hardware firewall in place between the BatchPatch computer and
> the target computers, you’ll need to configure it to allow DCE/RPC, so
> that it can open the necessary ports, on-the-fly, for each WMI
> connection. More info on DCE/RPC can be found at the following two
> links:
>
> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCE/RPC
>
> wiki.wireshark.org/DCE/RPC